# Round time in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

How to round time in format **%HH:%MM:%SS.%f** to **%HH:%MM:%SS** ?

e.g: `23:45:21.630` to `23:45:22`

Answer (score 1):

simple remove `%f`

```
dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 1):

use `strftime()` formatting function. For example:

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```